# Cannot install Swift cocoapod without use_frameworks! module-swift.h file not found

Tags: objective-c, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I have created two pods, one in Objc (PodA) and one in Swift (PodB). PodA depends on PodB, but cannot use use_frameworks! in the podfile (the larger Objc project I have that depends on PodA into also cannot use_frameworks!).

My issue is that PodA errors out when I have the line

```
#import <PodB/PodB-Swift.h>
```

saying that it cannot find the file. The issue seems to be with use_frameworks!. If I include that line in my podfile, it works, and when I don't it does not. Is there a way to workaround this issue? Again, having the line use_frameworks! is not an option for me if I want to use PodA in my larger project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `use_frameworks!` or `use_modular_headers!` in order to support modular imports.

Comment: It turns out that I need to  use_modular_headers! with @import PodB; in my project. #import <PodB/PodB-Swift.h> and #import "PodB-Swift.h" does not work. Thank you!